# Oracle SQL Date Time Inquiry

Tags: sql, oracle

So I have an oracle sql table that has information that looks like below:

```
USERID        DATETIME_STAMP               DESCR254   
=================================================================     
ZX08067       6/22/2012 4:26:03.589868 PM  Tools and Calculators
-------
-------
```

How would I retrieve the row shown by getting the exact DATETIME_STAMP?
I tried the below query, but it doesn't return any rows.  What's wrong with the DATETIME_STAMP part?

```
select * from sysadm.PS_IS_STATS_URLS
where USERID = 'ZX08067'
AND DESCR254 = 'Tools and Calculators'
and DATETIME_STAMP = (to_timestamp('22/06/2012 04:26.03.589868', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi.ss.ff'))
```

Comment: a) what type is datetime_stamp? b) Did you try a between statement?

Comment: a)datetime   b)no-what would that look like?

Comment: a) my guess is that this is your problem, but I'm not an oracle expert and don't have an oracle available right now.

Comment: b) select * from ... where datetime_stamp between (to_timestamp(...)) and (to_timestamp(...));  try this if it might be a rounding error.

Comment: the between query didn't return anything either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your database is clearly showing the time in 12-hour format with a "PM" suffix. Your query is using 24-hour time, so it's off by 12 hours. The query should be:

```
select * from sysadm.PS_IS_STATS_URLS
where USERID = 'ZX08067'
AND DESCR254 = 'Tools and Calculators'
and DATETIME_STAMP = (to_timestamp('22/06/2012 16:26.03.589868', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi.ss.ff'))
```